# Comparing a 3-tuple to a list of 3-tuples using only the first two parts of the tuple

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list of 3-tuples in a Python program that I'm building while looking through a file (so one at a time), with the following setup:

```
(feature,combination,durationOfTheCombination),
```

such that if a unique combination of feature and combination is found, it will be added to the list. The list itself holds a similar setup, but the durationOfTheCombination is the sum of all duration that share the unique combination of (feature,combination). Therefore, when deciding if it should be added to the list, I need to only compare the first two parts of the tuple, and if a match is found, the duration is added to the corresponding list item.

Here's an example for clarity. If the input is 
`(ABC,123,10);(ABC,123,10);(DEF,123,5);(ABC,123,30);(EFG,456,30)`
The output will be `(ABC,123,50);(DEF,123,5);(EFG,456,30)`.

Is there any way to do this comparison?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use Counter, you can use a dict instead.

```
setOf3Tuples = dict()

def add3TupleToSet(a):
  key = a[0:2]
  if key in setOf3Tuples:
    setOf3Tuples[a[0:2]] += a[2]
  else:
    setOf3Tuples[a[0:2]] = a[2]

def getRaw3Tuple():
  for k in setOf3Tuples:
    yield k + (setOf3Tuples[k],)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  add3TupleToSet(("ABC",123,10))
  add3TupleToSet(("ABC",123,10))
  add3TupleToSet(("DEF",123,5))
  print([i for i in getRaw3Tuple()])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter),

```
In [42]: from collections import Counter
In [43]: lst = [('ABC',123,10),('ABC',123,10),('DEF',123,5)]
In [44]: [(i[0],i[1],i[2]*j) for i,j in Counter(lst).items()]
Out[44]: [('DEF', 123, 5), ('ABC', 123, 20)]
```

As per the OP suggestion if it's have different values, use `groupby`

```
In [26]: lst = [('ABC',123,10),('ABC',123,10),('ABC',123,25),('DEF',123,5)]

In [27]: [tuple(list(n)+[sum([i[2] for i in g])]) for n,g in groupby(sorted(lst,key = lambda x:x[:2]), key = lambda x:x[:2])]
Out[27]: [('ABC', 123, 45), ('DEF', 123, 5)]
```

Comment: Your notation confuses me. Can you explain why you're multiple i[2] by j?

Comment: @Retroflux `i[2]` will give `10` and `10`, So it will multiply with it's count so `10 x 2 = 20`

Comment: Ahhhh, see here's the problem. The duration won't always be the same across all the combinations. For example, the (ABC,123,X) string could have another entry whose duration was 5, and the program then has to add that to the total duration (so the final sum would be a combination of the three, equaling (ABC,123,25)). I'll update the original post with a larger example.

Answer (score 1):

It seems a dict is more suited than a list here, with the first 2 fields as key. And to avoid checking each time if the key is already here you can use a defaultdict.

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(int)
for t in your_list:
    d[t[:2]] += t[-1]
```

Comment: For this answer, would you create the list and then convert it to a dictionary? The for loop suggests that I just read in all of the entries and then process them at the end. Am I reading this correctly?

Comment: I assumed you already have the list, but it's not necessary. If you process tuples one at a time, the idea is the same : create the dict, then create each tuple and add it to the dict in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your input is collected in a list as below, you can use pandas groupby to accomplish this quickly:

```
import pandas as pd
input = [('ABC',123,10),('ABC',123,10),('DEF',123,5),('ABC',123,30),('EFG',456,30)]
output = [tuple(x) for x in pd.DataFrame(input).groupby([0,1])[2].sum().reset_index().values]
```